# NodeJS Express - Endpoint to download files

Tags: node.js, express, download, pipe

recently I was working on a project where I stumbled upon a problem where I wasn't able to figure out a really satisfying solution.
I'd like to have an endpoint which let's a user download a file. I used Express' function `res.download(filename)` for this and it worked quite well. However, in my scenario the file is placed on a server so I have to download it first. What I am currently doing is requesting the file using the request module, saving it to the file system using fs and then letting the user download it. Afterwards I delete it.

I think this is not a nice solution and I was wondering if there's a better way.

I was trying around with something like this:

```
app.get('/download', (req, res) => {
const url = 'https://i.imgur.com/4BZWw57.jpg',
    r = request(url);

r.on('response', function(response) {
    response.pipe(res.download('response.headers.date'));
    console.log(response);
});
```

});

Is it possible to not save the file on my filesystem and rather instantly stream it to the user?

Comment: You would need to change the content-disposition header

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar like this:

```
app.get('/download', (req, res) => {
const url = 'https://i.imgur.com/4BZWw57.jpg',
    r = request(url);
    req.pipe(r);
    r.pipe(res);

});
```

Comment: But then it's not prompted as a download but the browser loads it, right? edit: tried it, yes, it it's loaded inside the browser